# Jupyterlab R kernel export pdf dataframe goes out of bounds because of dimensions text

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

[image]

As shown in the screenshot because of the "dimensions text" ("A data.frame: 9 x 7") the data frame cannot be centered and thus goes out of bounds horizontally. How can I disable this writing?